# Extract Text from a running Program's Window Title without process.MainWindowTitle

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to extract text from a Creo 2.0 Window Title.  The text will be used to create a folder titled the same as the part number that is opened and in the Window Title.  The issue I have is that I can iterate through, and find all the Window Titles of open applications using process.MainWindowTitle, but for some reason, Creo doesn't have a Main Window Title.  It also doesn't have the text using any other "process." functions.  I figure that the information has to be somewhere if it's in the title bar like other normal programs, but I'm just not going at it the right way.  Is there another process using C# that I can use to try and accomplish this?

Let me know if I need to give any other information.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does the processes title text (what shows up on the start-menu button for its window while running) have the text you are looking for?

Comment: Use debug and manually review the applications until you find it, then review the values in the watch window to decide how to best identify it.

Comment: @JakeHeidt Yes, the window has all the part information I need.

Comment: @JacobBrewer Hey.  I've found all the processes that are related to creo, but it just so happens that no Window Text, and really no useful text in general, is found in them.  You effectively said what I did after it didn't work the first time.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not necessarily be available via the `Process` object. Explorer.exe, for example, has the current folder name in the title bar but this is not the `MainWindowTitle`. Another option is to use UI Automation to inspect the UI and report the window's title. Depending on which version of .Net you are targeting, you can reference UiaComWrapper (which has more information and better perf, I believe) or UIAutomationClient and UIAutomationTypes. A short sample that prints all window titles:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Automation;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var windows = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, 
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window));
    foreach(AutomationElement window in windows)
    {
        var props = window.Current;
        var proc = Process.GetProcessById(props.ProcessId);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", props.ProcessId, proc.ProcessName, props.Name);
    }
}
```

Note that you need to run this elevated if you want to get information on elevated processes.

Comment: Thanks!  This works exactly as expected.  I edited your answer just a bit to add that you might have to browse to the references before this will work in Visual Studio.  The code worked perfectly once those were in though.